# Wireless broken by updates

Tags: wireless, 12.10, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

I just ran updates in 12.10 using update manager & now my wireless is not working. It worked great before the updates. Do you have any thoughts?

Specs:

- Laptop: HP Envy 6 Sleekbook
- RAM: 8GB
- HDD: 500GB
- SSD: 32GB
- GPU: ATI Radeon HD 7430
- WiFi: Broadcom 4313

Comment: No, visit the link that read the answer I provided. It shows several ways to install the Broadcom Wireless drivers. Test it out and let me know over there if one of the ways worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your wifi driver is enabled?.. check it in

**software sources -> additional drivers**

if it is not enabled. try by enabling it.Comment if problem is not solved.

Comment: Obviously that was one of the FIRST things I checked.